# Windows authentication multiple requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Windows Authentication to secure ASP.NET MVC5 application.

Everything works ok, I'm prompted to enter credentials via browser popup, and content it served properly.

However I do notice constantly that some requests are being sent 2 times, or more, with receiving 401 (Unauthorized) code, but shortly after requests are issued again and 200 (OK) is returned.

I assume that is part of negotiation with WWW-Authenticate and Authorize requests headers, but what is unclear to me is why this has to happen all the time even though credentials were supplied at the very start?

Is this normal behavior?
If not, how can it be fixed?
If yes, is it a big performance hit?

Attached is the combined screenshot of Fiddler and Firefox developer console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the normal behavior. Here is a (very) short description of how the authentication works:

1. Request is sent to server (without credentials) => not authenticated (your first request)
2. Server responds with 401 (Access denied)
3. Browser gets error and sends credentials back => authenticated (your second request)

After the 3rd step, if the server has not received the requested credentials, it sends another 401 response and the browser displays the 401 error page. A more complete description can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx#pagexplained0001_ntlmauthentication).

Comment: That's fine, but should this happen all the time? Is there a way to tell browser to send same credentials all the time to specific domain, or it always has to do request without credentials and then send them after 401 is received? I'm talking about subsequent requests of course.

Comment: @BarisaPuter, this is the defined protocol. I don't know if there's a way of bypassing it. I edited my answer and posted a link with more information.

Comment: I read  that article and still confused.. I get how authentication initially established and there are like a billion articles describing that part. But as far as I can tell the TTL for ticket is very short and periodically needs to be renewed by client. Also, this takes a little time, so often see multiple requests fail with 401 (like 2-5, if sent within short period of time such as requesting .js and .css files and stuff) before finally getting the "real" response. And this happens like every 5-10 minutes in my enviros, but I suspect TTL is configurable by AD controller or something

Comment: Does the browser popup every time you have 401 response? My application works using integrated authentication and I see 401 a couple of times when monitoring in the network tab in chrome but I only see when I logged in but nothing after that.